# Laravel - Undefined variable when no data exists when filtered in database

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, foreach

I am having a struggle with an error I am getting: `Undefined variable: orbitdata`.
I have looked at some answers and I know this happens when there is no data in the database that matches the filter that I have in the controller.  If there is data there is no problem.

The controller I am using is this:

```
$satellite = DB::table('satellites')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->get(); 
$data = DB::table('satellites')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->get();
$orbitalelements = DB::table('tle')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->get();
return view('pages/satellite', compact($data, 'data', $orbitalelements, 'orbitalelements'));
```

The logic behind the controller is to filter the database by norad_cat_id and return the row which has the same norad_cat_id.

The 'tle' table might not have any data for the filtered norad_cat_id, so $orbitalelements returns no data. When it does not I get this error.

My blade file contains this foreach statement for the $orbitalelements variable:

```
@foreach($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)
@endforeach
```

I have tried adding an isset statement (which did not work):

```
@if(isset($orbitalelements))
    @foreach($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)
    @endforeach
@endif
```

How do you make it so that I don't get an Undefined variable error when there is no data from the database to return?

**EDIT:** Here is my full blade file:

```
<div class="satellite-content">
    <div class="main-satellite-data">
        <ul>
        @foreach($data as $satellite)
            <span id="satellite-name">{{$satellite->satname}}</span>
            <li><span id="intldes">INTLDES: </span>{{$satellite->intldes}}</li>
            <li><span id="noradid">NORAD Cat ID: </span>{{$satellite->norad_cat_id}}</li>
            <li><span>Object Type: </span>{{$satellite->object_type}}</li>
            <li><span>Country: </span>{{$satellite->country}}</li>
            <li><span>Launch Date: </span>{{$satellite->launch}}</li>
            <li><span>Launch Site: </span>{{$satellite->site}}</li>
            <ul> 
                <li id="list-name"><span>ORBITAL ELEMENTS</span></li>
                <li><span id="inclination">Inclination: </span>{{$satellite->inclination}}</li>
                <li><span id="period">Period: </span>{{$satellite->period}}</li>
                <li><span id="apogee">Apogee: </span>{{$satellite->apogee}}</li>
                <li><span id="perigee">Perigee: </span>{{$satellite->perigee}}</li>
                <li><span id="decay">Decay: </span>{{$satellite->decay}}</li>
            @endforeach
            @forelse($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)
                <li><span id="epoch">Epoch: </span>{{$orbitdata->epoch}}</li>
                <li><span id="meanmotion">Mean Motion: </span>{{$orbitdata->mean_motion}}</li>
                <li><span id="eccentricity">Eccentricity: </span>{{$orbitdata->eccentricity}}</li>
                <li><span id="meananomaly">Mean Anomaly: </span>{{$orbitdata->mean_anomaly}}</li>
                <li><span id="bstar">Bstar: </span>{{$orbitdata->bstar}}</li>
            </ul>
            @empty
            <p>no data</p>
            @endforelse
        </ul>
        <div class="map-tle-padding">
            <div id="satellitemap"></div>
            <div class="tle-data">
                <ul>
                    <li id="list-name-tle"><span>TLE Data</span></li>
                    @forelse($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)
                    <li id="tle-data-main">{{$orbitdata->tle_line0}}</li>
                    <li id="tle-data-main">{{$orbitdata->tle_line1}}</li>
                    <li id="tle-data-main">{{$orbitdata->tle_line2}}</li>
                    @empty
                    <p>no data</p>
                    @endforelse
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Results:
Without data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpIwN.png

With data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BnFH.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel includes an option for this:

```
@forelse($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)
  ...
@empty
  ...No data...
@endforelse
```

Also, you are using `compact` wrong.  It should just be:

```
return view('pages/satellite', compact('data', 'orbitalelements'));
```

Comment: what the problem here : `@foreach($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)` !?  ,for and foreach will not work if `$orbitalelements` not sets.

Comment: That does fix the undefined variable error for the pages that don't have the data, but for the pages that have data it gets shown twice (ie. anything in the $orbitdata duplicates)

Comment: Once for each row in your database, right? It's a foreach loop.

Comment: Yes. It is exactly for the same for the $data variable.

Comment: The top piece runs once per entry in your array, the bottom runs if the array is empty. If you're seeing different behavior, post a dump of your data and what you're seeing

Comment: @Jeff I have posted screenshots of the result and my full blade file.

Comment: Yea it looks like those are two separate database rows, you've got different values for "Epoch" in the two results

Comment: @Jeff I can confirm that I apparently had two separate database rows. I missed it due to the fact I have 80,000 rows in my database! Is there any chance I can only pull the latest row (the row that has the latest epoch from the database)? That should solve the duplicate problem.

Comment: `$orbitalelements = DB::table('tle')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->orderBy('epoch', 'DESC')->first();`

Comment: @Jeff Managed to solve it - had to change it to `$orbitalelements = DB::table('tle')->where('norad_cat_id', $norad_cat_id)->orderBy('epoch_microseconds', 'DESC')->take(1)->get();` Works like a charm now!

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(count($orbitalelements))
  @foreach($orbitalelements as $orbitdata)
  @endforeach
@endif
```

Should work since `count($orbitalelements)` count is zero, which is falsy.